# Is this a common garden spider?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Spotted this outside my window today. Looks like an orb-weaver, but I can't tell whether it's a regular garden spider or not. What species could this be?

This picture was taken in Bangalore, Karnataka, India.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> Looks like an orb-weaver ..

I agree! This spider definitely belongs to the genus *[Argiope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argiope_(spider))*, though, due to the angle of your provided image, it's difficult to be more specific than that (if I had to guess, *A. anasuja*).

The confidence in my genus suggestion comes from the stance the spider is displaying. Spiders within the *Argiope* genus carry a common nickname of "signature spiders", due to the fact that they'll intertwine additional webbing within their web, called [stabilimentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_decoration), that, given the design of the support webbing and the spider's stance, will allow for the spider to appear much larger than it really is.

[image]

If you can provide an image that reveals the top of the abdomen, a more confident species suggestion may be possible.

> Is this a common garden spider?

From the looks of it so far -- yes, this is a common garden spider.